# GraphRepository and autogenerating code for method findByName(String) don't works

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

When I uncomment this line in this interface I get error while Spring run.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person>
{
    //Person findByName(String name);
}
```

Output from run:

```
2016-06-08 23:27:58.580  INFO 6723 --- [           main] o.s.d.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext  : Neo4jMappingContext initialisation completed
2016-06-08 23:27:58.665  WARN 6723 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hello.PersonRepository hello.HomeController.personRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
2016-06-08 23:27:58.671  INFO 6723 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-06-08 23:27:58.695 ERROR 6723 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hello.PersonRepository hello.HomeController.personRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hello.PersonRepository hello.HomeController.personRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.java:43) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2016-06-08 23:27:58.707  INFO 6723 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/marcin/Praca%20magisterska/spring_data_neo4j/neo4j_connection/target/classes/, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-core/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-api/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-api-2.0.1.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-compiler/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-compiler-2.0.1.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-http-driver/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/marcin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar]
```

Implementation of class Person:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person
{
  @GraphId
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  private Person() {}

  public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

  (...)

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I have expected that Spring generate code for findByName(String). I don't understand why it don't do that and I don't understand error returned by Java. Can anyone explain this problem?

--

Tree dependency from Maven:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Neo4j-CMS 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ Neo4j-CMS ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] org.marcin:Neo4j-CMS:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.13; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.20; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.20; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.20; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.6:compile - version managed from 2.7.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.14; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-compiler:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile (version managed from 4.3.6)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 1.12.1.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.19; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:runtime - version managed from 1.7.13; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 4.2.5.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.19; scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO]    |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.33:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.33:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile (version managed from 3.2.1.Final)
[INFO]    |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.6:compile (version managed from 2.6.0)
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.2.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.1.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.367 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-09T22:07:03+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/339M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please share your dependency tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Spring Data Commons is the problem. If you stick with the release train that SDN 4.1.1 belongs to (Hopper SR1), then you should be fine.

[This](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/#quick-start) shows you how to do it:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Hopper-SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```